# How to loop while creating a view

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops

I'm trying to generate a view with variables (i want to generate statistical reports), i've tried this :

```
Do $$
yr_max integer;
yr_min integer;
i integer :=an_min;

BEGIN
 SELECT GREATEST end_year FROM schema.table INTO yr_max;
 SELECT LEAST start_year FROM schema.table INTO yr_min;

 CASE 
        WHEN "type"=2 THEN 'AAAA'
        WHEN "type"=1 THEN 'BBBB'
        ELSE 'other'
 END AS type_orp,
 
 FOR i IN yr_min..yr_max LOOP -- for each year
        ROUND(SUM(case when "start_year ">=i and "end_year "< i+1 then "area" end)) as 'tot_'||to_char(i), --sum of surfaces per year
    END LOOP;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But i'm pretty sure that it's not possible to put a loop in a select right ?

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me what you want to do. Do you want to produce a view (a pivot?) with a dynamic list of columns, depending on the data? If that's the case a "dynamic SQL statement" will do the trick.

Comment: Yes ! i want to have the sum of area used per year and per type. Im gonna check this

Comment: conditional aggregation, analytic functions, recursive CTE... ... I'm not sure what you're after.  Example data  and expected results would improve our understanding of what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @xQbert yes i can imagine but i still dont get how to post extract of table or line break on this site

Comment: To generate a [nice table data for question](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)  adn then format it as a code block.  or post the SQL to create table or use an online database we can reference with tables & Data populated.  (Such as rextester)

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Thank you ! this will be usefull :)